# Пунктуация в предложениях со вставкой

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

> Подкараулил этого кота гражданин в тот момент, когда животное с вороватым видом (что же поделаешь, что у котов такой вид? Это не оттого, что они порочны, а оттого, что они боятся, чтобы кто-либо из существ более сильных, чем они — собаки и люди — не причинили им какой-нибудь вред или обиду. И то и другое очень нетрудно, но чести в этом, уверяю, нет никакой. Да, нет никакой!), да, так с вороватым видом кот собирался устремиться зачем-то в лопухи (Булг.).

По-моему,в предложении "чтобы кто-либо из существ более сильных, чем они — собаки и люди — не причинили им какой-нибудь вред или обиду", где *собаки и люди* - вставная конструкция, нужна запятая после *люди*. Сравнительный оборот *чем они* надо закрыть запятой.  Или запятая нужна после *они*?

Answer (score 2):

В моём варианте "Мастера и Маргариты" напечатано так:" (что же поделаешь, что у котов такой вид? Это не оттого, что они порочны,  а  оттого, что  они боятся, чтобы  кто-либо из  существ  более сильных, чем они, — собаки и люди, — не причинили им какой-нибудь вред или обиду. И то  и другое  очень нетрудно, но чести в этом, уверяю, нет никакой. Да,  нет никакой!), да,  так с  вороватым  видом кот  собирался устремиться зачем-то в лопухи."

Так что появляется другой вопрос: почему две запятых и два тире? Кажется, это можно объяснить тем, что в 19 и начале 20 века прибегали к сочетанию запятой и тире для более сильного выделения чего-либо: http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-060.htm. Нашла, когда думала над Гоголем. Здесь тоже можно применить.

Comment: У Булгакова запятых нет, проверил по нескольким источникам. Так что обсуждаем не Булгакова, а мнение некоего редактора. 
Тем не менее. С первой запятой как раз всё понятно. "Чем они" - это законченный оборот. "Люди и собаки" относится не к "они", а к "существам, более сильным, так что первая запятая вполне логично могда бы закрывать сравнительный оборот. А вот вторая-то откуда?!

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря, сам засомневался. Но могу сказать одно, у Булгакова с его феноменальным чувством текста орфографических (включая пунктуационные) ошибок не бывает. Только намеренное отступление.  Так что, если это не редакторский произвол, копайте глубже.

Ну давайте попробуем вместе разобраться. Для начала: где должна бы стоять эта гипотетическая запятая? Если после "люди", то получится ерунда: "они - собаки и люди". Смысл явно не тот. Снимаем. Остается, что "собаки и люди" относится к "более сильным", значит запятая могла бы стоять только после "чем они". Убираем "собак и людей", т.е. упрощаем до  "... кто-либо из существ более сильных, чем они(,) ... не причинили им какой-нибудь вред". Нужна тут запятая? Интуитивно - да, хочется поставить: "[более сильных], чем они, ..." - воспринимается как вполне законченный сравнительный оборот.
Если так, то остаётся только предположить, что запятая "поглощается" тире. На тему такого "поглощения" я уже не раз пытался поговорить, сколько бы меня не закидывали помидорами.

Comment: У Роз.: 

перед первым тире запятая, если требует структура первой части основного предл.: Он посмотрел на пепелище, которое окружало его, — какой ужас! — и руки бессильно опустились у него — запятая закрывает придат. часть сложнопод. предл.; перед вторым тире запятая, если этого требует структура второй части основного предл. или самой вставной конструкции:  Он встал и, прихрамывая — он был на протезе, — подошёл к окну. — вставное предложение примыкает к деепричастию, и запятая ставится после всей этой конструкции. Зап. перед _они_, так как собаки и люди не примыкает к срав.обороту?